# How to get old whatsapp account back without using the current cellphone number?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4

My Samsung Galaxy S4 recently broke. I've had a different whatsapp number and a different cellphone number. How do I get all my contacts back without using the current cellphone number but the whatsapp account number?

Comment: @AndrewT. The suggested duplicate has an answer only for when the phone number stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the SIM for verification. Just pop the SIM into any phone and enter the old WhatsApp number during setup.

After a 5 min wait of trying to verify from the other phone(which won't work as the number is different) you will receive an SMS on the other WhatsApp SIM. Just enter the code received on this phone on the phone with the current SIM and you should be able to use the old WhatsApp account.